# Webpack - use CopyWebpackPlugin for scss files

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, scss-lint

I want to convert some files from `*.scss` extension to `*.css` one and then copy them to the target folder .

These files aren't a part of a module so I can't import them by the `*.scss` loader (i.e `import "myStyle.scss"`).

I know how to copy files by the [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin) plugin  -

```
plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([    
        { from: 'source/myStyle.scss', to: 'myStyle.css' }
    ])
]
```

So now all I need is to add it a conversion from `scss` to `css`  before to copying .

How could I achieve that ?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [transform](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin#transform) option of CopyWebpackPlugin plugin in conjunction with `sass`. I.e. use the [`sass.compile`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/js-api/modules#compile) function:

```
const sass = require('sass');

plugins: [
  new CopyWebpackPlugin(
    [
      {
        from: 'style.scss',
        to: 'style.css',
        transform: (content, path) => {
          return sass.compile(path).css
        },
      }
    ],
  ),
]
```

Note that older answers may recommend using `sass.renderSync()`, but this is now [deprecated](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/js-api/modules#renderSync).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need `sass-loader` for that.
For more info, check out https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader

Update: Try something like this.

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('myStyle.css')
  ]
```

Comment: See my edit. There's no way around the `rules` section, unfortunately.